# How to call the function to pass the value in this code? C++

Tags: c++, function, loops, callback

I am trying to do the homework but I can't figure how to continue from here. The assignment requires to design a calculator for controlling budget. Here are the requirements:

Have you ever been low on cash and couldn’t go beyond a certain dollar limit when shopping? You sort of need a calculator in your head. It would be cool if a device was actually part of the cart and as you add an item into the cart it would increment your total counter. To solve this, we are going to write a program that keeps a tally of the amount that we have spent so far as we visit a store.

What Your Program Should Do:

1. Allow the shopper (user) to enter in the product name and the cost. This should be echoed and confirmed. Make sure to check for bad data.
2. The user should be allowed to continue this until they want to check out.
3. Your program needs to keep a running total.
4. Upon checkout, the grand total should be displayed.

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <fstream>
   #include <string>
   #include <iomanip>

   using namespace std;

   int item_info(float, char);

   int main()
   {

       //Declare all varibles.
       char itemName[100];
       float itemPrice;
       char option;
       float total;
       int count;

       count = 1;

       // Setting decimal point for output.
       cout.setf(ios::fixed, ios::floatfield);
       cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
       cout.precision(2);

       item_info(itemPrice, itemName[100]);
       total = total + itemPrice;

       //Ask user if they want to continued to add more items.
       cout << "Do you want to add more items? (Y/N)";
       cin >> option;

       if (option == 'Y' || option == 'y')
       {
           item_info(itemPrice, itemName[100]);

       }
       else
       {
           cout << "The total price of all items: $" << total << ".\n";
       }

       }

   int item_info(float itemPrice, char itemName[100])
       {
       //Ask for input.
       cout << "Please enter the item name: ";
       cin.get(itemName, '\n');

       //Ask for the price of the item.
       cout << "Please enter the price of the item: ";
       cin >> itemPrice;

       //Check if it's a valid data.
       while (!cin)
       {
           cin.clear();
           cin.ignore(100, '\n');
           cout << "Invalid input! Please enter the item price:";
           cin >> itemPrice;
       }
       //Only take necessary data.
       cin.ignore(100, '\n');

       //Confirm the user input.
       cout << "Item information:" << itemName <<": " << itemPrice <<"\n";
       return itemPrice;
       }
   ```

Can someone tell me how to fix it ?

Comment: Don't use a `float` to represent a money value: not enough precision. Once you've used two significant figures for pence / cents, you only have about 5 left for pounds / dollars.

Comment: Use `std::string`, that will solve all your problems

Comment: You shouldn't use floating point for money generally as the datatypes are not precise enough. Just calculate in cents and only convert to floating point (if needed) when printing the value.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall I want to see how you calculate the total from just using `std::string`

Comment: @Simon, the op's code doesn't even compile because of his `char[]` usage, and you are talking about floating point precision...

Answer (score 0):

You have two obvious problems: First is that the declaration and definition of `item_info` doesn't match. One takes a single character, the other an array of characters.

The second problem is that you call the function with a single character, but the problem is that you index out of bounds of the `itemName` array.

My guess is that the function is supposed to take a *string* (i.e. an array of characters), which means that the declaration and the call are wrong. You should not use an index when calling the function, just pass `itemName` like any other argument (see e.g. `itemPrice`).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `item_info` parameters differ in definition and declaration:

```
int item_info(float, char);//should be char[100]
int item_info(float itemPrice, char itemName[100])
{
<...>
}
```

Second, here you are passing only the 100th element of the array, not the array itself:

```
item_info(itemPrice, itemName[100]); //should be  item_info(itemPrice, itemName);
```

Finally, you should really use `std::string` for that, it will help you avoid such problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your `item_info` function return an int, and you don't use this return value anywhere.

If you want to use `itemPrice` and `itemName` as an in/out parameters, you need to use a reference `&`.
Also, why not use `std::string` instead of a char array?

And as the other answers mentions. The declaration and definition of `item_info` doesn't match.